# Determine if PowerShell script has been run from the desktop or command line

Tags: powershell

Windows Explorer (desktop) has the ability to run a PowerShell script by right-clicking and selecting "Run with PowerShell". However, as the window is closed when the script has finished, any messages are lost. So one could stick a "Press any key" at the end. However, that would be very annoying when run from the PowerShell command prompt.

Is there a way for PowerShell to determine where it was run from? Specifically, the desktop?

Comment: PowerShell is nothing to do with server management?? *sigh*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Run with PowerShell*s `$myinvocation.line` is taken from corresponding registry key. For instance, on (my) *Windows 8.1* with *PS version 5.1*:

```
PS D:\PShell> $auxRegKey='\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command'
PS D:\PShell> (get-itemproperty -literalpath HKLM:$auxRegKey).'(default)'
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
PS D:\PShell>
```

The following code snippet could help:

```
'script ouput here'
$auxRegKey='\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command'
$auxRegVal=(get-itemproperty -literalpath HKLM:$auxRegKey).'(default)'
$auxRegCmd=$auxRegVal.Split(' ',3)[2].Replace('%1', $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
if ("`"$($myinvocation.Line)`"" -eq $auxRegCmd) {
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + ': supposedly run via explorer right click'
    $x = Read-Host
} else {
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + ': run from CLI'    # optional
}
```

The script says ***supposedly*** because we could imagine following (*improbable*) command from an open `cmd` window (or even its equivalent from `PowerShell` prompt):

```
==> "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'D:\PShell\SF\q866281.ps1'"
script ouput here
D:\PShell\SF\q866281.ps1: supposedly run via explorer right click

==>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - so you're suggesting looking in the registry to find the full command path that the desktop uses to build the invocation and testing against that. Yes, I can see that working. Bit fiddly but what the heck

Comment: Okay, really smelly code but marked as the answer :-) Let's hope Microsoft doesn't change the registry key entry drastically - but as long as they leave that %1 in there, it'll hang together

Comment: Well I never! Fateful words that I wrote above and here we are three years later and Microsoft *have* changed the registry key. The '\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command' key no longer exists in build 2004 :-(

Comment: In version 2004, you have to check these key: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.ps1\Shell\0\Command

Comment: @RobNicholson - well done ! (What blooming awful break… )

Answer (score 2):

There is a variable named `$myinvocation` will return a `InvocationInfo Class` object. It contains various information about how the script was invoked.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.invocationinfo(v=vs.85).aspx

You could do something like this to reach your goal.

```
"hello world"
if ($myinvocation.line) {
    "run from cli"
} else {
    "run via explorer right click"
    $x = read-host
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `run from cli` with right click as well. (Using PS version 5.1)

Comment: What version of Powershell are you running? I am using Version 3.

Comment: When run from the desktop, I get Line:  if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & 'C:\Users\HeliosComms(RobNicho\OneDrive - Helios Medical Communications\My Scripts\Run-Test.ps1'

Comment: I'm guessing your running a script named `run-test.ps1`... If that line code does not appear in the `run-test.ps1` script, it may be coming from the User or Machine Powershell profile. Is there some sort of error it is throwing? Is it actually running the `run-test.ps1` script?

Comment: Yes, it's running the script fine. That invocation line must be what Windows 10 tacks on the front when running from the desktop. So this is PowerShell v5

Comment: So I can't test for $myinvocation.line being null as in my case, it contains values albeit different values when run from desktop or from PowerShell. I wonder if there is something in the $Global scope you could test?

Comment: Look for differences in other properties of the Invocation class object described in the MSDN article. Or maybe try a different kind of test like `if ($myInvocation.line -notmatch "ExecutionPolicy")`

Comment: Hmm, just compared $Global variables between run from within PowerShell or from desktop and they are identical. I wonder if looking at the parent process would help?